# Firebug css file

Tags: firebug

I have a question about firebug concerning the .CSS pages...

On the right 'Style' you've got the css... Furter on to the right you have the name of the css.file... Normally this is refering to the correct css file... But sometimes i get something like 'template...r=default (line 458)', so i'm not able to find the file inmediatly. Is this a setting i can change? On the server or in firebug/firefox?

Thx...

Comment: does it show the full file name if you hover over the name?

Answer (score 0):

If you hover your mouse over the link it should give you the full filename.
I don't think there's a setting for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you rightclick the name (or name fragment) in Firebug, you can copy its url to the clipboard or even open it directly in a new tab.